# gameobject というタグは何のために作ったのか？

Tags: 討議, タグ

Unityの質問で見かけましたがこの何の意味もない gameobject タグは誰が何の目的で作ったのでしょうか。
たしかにUnityに限らずゲームエンジンでは GameObject という名前のクラスを作ることが多いのですが、なぜその名前でタグを作ろうと思ったのか？？？

タグの説明では

> Unity3Dフレームワークで、シーン内のあらゆるオブジェクトのベースとなるクラス。

、とあって確かにそうなんですが、なぜそれをタグにしようと思った・・・

Comment: 確かに混乱を招くタグですね。`unity3d-gameobject`のがまだマシに見えました。自分も不要ではないかと考えます。

Comment: 一応本家の方でもこのタグはありまして、unity3dのgameobjectに関する質問用に用意されているようです。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gameobject

Answer (score 3):

誰が何の目的で作ったか、への直接的な回答ではありませんが:

そのタグの説明を付けたのは私です<sup>(1)</sup>。英語版SOに`gameobject`タグが存在し、80件程使われているのを見て、あって損はないタグなのだろうと判断しました。今回振り返ってみた反省点として、今後英語版での使われ方を参考にする時は、メタの方でタグの廃棄処分が検討されていないかを`burninate-request`タグと[共に検索](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bburninate-request%5D+gameobject)して確認しようと思います。（`gameobject`に関しては廃棄処分は今のところ検討されていませんでした。）

---

それはさておいて、もともとどういう事情だったかに関わらず、現在の質問の動向をみて最適なタグ付けを考えてよいと思います。

Unityに詳しくないので、一般論としての意見になりますが:

`gameobject`は一般名称に聞こえるので、`unity3d-gameobject`の方がよいと思います。

参考として、[gamedev.seの`gameobject`タグ](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameobject)はごく一般的な「ゲーム内オブジェクト」という定義を与えられているものの、実際に付けられている質問にはUnityにおける`GameObject`に関する質問もあり、定義と違った使われ方をされがちなようです。

また、「Unityの`GameObject`自体に関する問題が複数投稿されるだろう」と想定し得るならば、[unity3d](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)に関する質問をさらに分類するためのものとして、`unity3d-gameobject`というタグの存在意義は**ある**と思います。サイドバーの「関連する質問」には同じタグのついた質問が出てきやすい<sup>(2)</sup>ので、フレームワークや言語のタグに加え、さらに分類するタグを付けておくことで質問を探しやすくなります。

---

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> タグの説明の編集履歴は、[タグの情報タブ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/gameobject/info)を開き、「履歴」「抜粋履歴」リンクをクリックすると確認できます。作成者は、[分類学者バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist)が授与された、つまり50個以上の質問で使われたタグにしか表示されないようです。</sup>

<sup><sup>(2)</sup> [Stack Overflow ポッドキャスト #32](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/podcast-32/)の21:40あたりから (英語): 「関連する質問」には、タイトル・タグ（もっとも重み付けされている）・本文（最頻語を除去したもの）を元にマッチングした質問が表示される。</sup>

Comment: GameObjectはUnityに存在するクラスの1つですがタグにするほどのものではないです。タグの整理をどういうポリシーでやるかについては決まってないと思いますが、そのうちなるようになるでしょう。

Comment: @ぽぽたん [gamedev.seで、GameObjectに言及しているが、gameobjectタグが付いていない質問](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=gameobject%20-%5bgameobject%5d%20%5bunity%5d)を眺めていると、他の言語でクラス階層の頂点にいるオブジェクトクラスのような印象で、普遍的な存在という感じがしますね。あまりにも普遍的なので、Unity内でも一般名詞のようなものであり、極端に言うとUnityイコールGameObject、のような。「タグにするほど独立したトピックではない」ということであれば納得です。私の意見は出しつくしたので、あとはUnityを知っている方々にゆだねます。